# Duplicate things a specific number of times in racket

Tags: loops, for-loop, recursion, racket, repeat

I'm trying to write a program that takes in a phrase and a number (n) and returns a list that contains the phrase repeated n times.
What I have so far looks like this, but it clearly only repeats the phrase twice:

```
(define (duplicate num phrase)
  (list phrase phrase))
```

Example of desired input/output:

`(duplicate 3 'Hello)` produces `'(Hello Hello Hello)`.

Is there a way to do this recursively?

Answer (score 1):

The function you want is exactly `make-list`:

```
> (make-list 3 'Hello)
'(Hello Hello Hello)
```

But since you asked for a recursive function, you can write one out in the standard way.

```
(define (duplicate num phrase)
  (cond
    [(zero? num) empty]
    [else (cons phrase (duplicate (sub1 num) phrase))]))
```

You also tagged this with for-loop, so here's a version that uses `for/list`.

```
(define (duplicate num phrase)
  (for/list ([num num])
    phrase))
```